# Change the default browser value using c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, registry

I am working on one small issue and I want to set the Default Directory at runtime. so I have implemented the code below and still it is not working though it is not giving me any error.

[image]

I have wrote the code as specified below. please let me know what is the mistake in the code?

```
    HKEY hKey;
LPCTSTR sk = TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main");
LPCTSTR value = TEXT("Default Download Directory");
LPCTSTR newValue = TEXT("C:\\Users\\USRNAME\\PROJ\\My Files");

LONG lRes = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sk,0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
bool bExistsAndSuccess(lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS);
RegCloseKey(hKey);

if (bExistsAndSuccess)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, ptr, _T("bingo, Found you & key"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);


        if (RegSetValueEx(hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)newValue, sizeof(newValue)+1) != ERROR_SUCCESS)               
        {
            RegCloseKey(hKey);
            MessageBox(NULL, ptr, _T("bingo, success"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, ptr, _T("bingo, failure"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, ptr, _T("bingo, Found you without key"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
```

It shows me bingo, success message box but value is not updating in the registry. please help me.

Comment: Since `newValue` is a pointer, `sizeof(newValue)+1` is always either 5 or 9.

Comment: I have changed code from other posts, `if (RegSetValueEx(hKey, value, NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE &)newValue, sizeof(newValue)+1) != ERROR_SUCCESS);` but still it isnot working.

Comment: `ERROR_SUCCESS` means that the operation completed successfully.

Comment: I'll try to make it clearer: `newValue` is a pointer. `sizeof(newValue)` is not the length of the string, it's the size of a pointer; 4 or 8. If the code you copied worked, it must have used an array, not a pointer. Try `TCHAR newValue[] = ...`.

Comment: Replace `sizeof(newValue)+1` with `strlen(newValue)+1`

Comment: You RegCloseKey(hKey); before you call RegSetValueEx(hKey,...)

Comment: yea..
I found few issues.

#1 used `RegCloseKey` code before SetValue. I've removed the code from there.

#2 sizeof(newValue) will give result size for pointer not value. so I have changed it to `_tcslen(newValue) * sizeof(TCHAR)+1`
now it's working :)

thank you everyone for help.

Answer (score 1):

As molbdnilo mentioned, newValue is a pointer. sizeof(newValue) is not the length of the string. so I have changed the code with `_tcslen(newValue) * sizeof(TCHAR)+1`

& as per the comments of Vlad, I have removed to `RegCloseKey` statement which is executed before `RegSetValueEx`